# Android Same app bundle for multiple os versions

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

How to use the same app bundle & based on minimum SDK & target SDK versions for the old API version it would be a very lite version of the app with less Gradle dependencies & code.

The old way to implement this to have two projects with one key store signing & to upload multiple Apks.

Is there a difference while using the app bundle or I have to generate multiple app bundles & upload them on google play?

Please note the core library is not applicable here because the full project is up & running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically two options:

- Use of [conditional delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/conditional-delivery#minapi-condition) which supports serving parts of your app above or below a certain API version.
- Publish two separate Android App Bundles with a different `minSdkVersion` and different `versionCodes` (similarly to how you published multiple APKs).

Hope that helps.